# how can I find names of functions based on --trace-opt output

Tags: v8

node --trace-opt and --trace-deopt
outputs hex and sfi, but not always names of functions. so I wanted to know if there is any other flags I can set to know which function are getting optimized/deoptimaized.
(such subjects are above my knowledge level but I'm really curious)

I looked at other available flags of --v8-options, checked outputs of other trace and log flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all functions have names. When a function doesn't have a name, V8 can't print one -- what name would you expect it to print?

For example: When you write:

```
function sum1(a, b) { return a + b; }
for (let i = 0; i < 1e5; i++) sum1(2, 3);
```

You'll see in `--trace-opt` output:

```
[marking 0x2a920019a879 <JSFunction sum1 (sfi = 0x2a920019a609)> for optimization ...
```

There's even some amount of name inference for some functions that technically don't have a name, as this example of an anonymous function stored in a global variable shows:

```
var sum2 = function(a, b) { return a + b; }
for (let i = 0; i < 1e5; i++) sum2(2, 3);
```

gives:

```
[marking 0x2a920004e101 <JSFunction sum2 (sfi = 0x2a920019a63d)> for optimization ...
```

And then there are truly anonymous functions, which in particular tend to occur as callbacks:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1e5; i++) ((a, b) => a + b)(2, 3);
for (let i = 0; i < 1e5; i++) (function(a, b) { return a + b; })(2, 3);
```

can't give you anything more meaningful than:

```
[marking 0x2a920009d379 <JSFunction (sfi = 0x2a920019a671)> for optimization
```

One conclusion you may take away from this is that for inspectability/profiling/stacktraces/etc, it can make sense to make sure all your functions have names.

One particular case of an anonymous function is the code in the top level. The top level rarely ever gets optimized in real code, but tends to get optimized a lot in tiny examples (like the snippets above) where people just put their long-running `for`-loops into the top level, causing OSR-optimization. Maybe that's what confused you. This, too, can be worked around manually for more descriptive tracing output: just wrap everything else into a function, like so:

```
(function toplevel() {
  
  // Your code here, e.g.:
  function sum1(...) ...
  for (...) sum1(...);

})();
```